# Can I use a dryer circuit to feed a sub-panel and the dryer?

Tags: subpanel

I need to install a sub panel. I have a 30 amp dryer outlet in my utility room already. Can use the wire to put in a 30 amp 240 volt sub panel and then use one leg to run my dryer outlet and then run a 20 amp 120 volt breaker on the other leg without tripping the 30 amp breaker in my main panel?

Comment: What will be running off the other breaker?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the dryer outlet box please?

Answer (score 4):

Your dryer (almost certainly - there are a few "apartment dryers" and new-ish heat pump dryers that use 120V, but virtually all others use 240V) uses both legs.

Depending on the details of the wiring of your 30A dryer outlet, you may not be able to put a sub-panel here at all, without re-wiring. Up to 1996 is was allowed to use ungrounded NEMA 10 dryer outlets, and if the connection is via cable that does not have **both** neutral **and** ground conductors, you'll need to retrofit ground or otherwise upgrade that connection, as sub-panels have required a 4-wire connection for a much longer time.

If you can put a sub-panel in here and are sensible about using large loads only when not running the dryer, it would likely be fine. Otherwise, you'll trip the breaker sometimes, unless you upgrade the service to the sub-panel.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a 4 wire connection to go to the sub panel. I want to power my shed with the 20 amp. Was hoping I could use the existing 10 gauge wire so I didn't have to pull new wire into the main panel

Comment: You could get a heat pump dryer. Depending where you are, you might even be able to get a utility company or other rebate on the purchase. Then you would only have 2 20A 120V circuits to feed rather than a 240V 30A and a 120V 20A

Comment: Heat pump driers don't vent warm moist air. They dump water into a drain, and keep blowing the same air around the dryer, into a dehumidifier, and back into the clothes, until the clothes are dry.

Comment: @FreeMan yeah, heat pump dryers are basically a dehumidifier and a tumbler.  Same as if you had a closed room where you hung up clothes on a line, and then had dehumidifiers running in the room and a fan to stir the air in the room.  It's like that. No need for air exchange, the water ends up in the dehumidifier tank or drain.

Comment: @Ecnerwal you state above "sub-panels have required a 4-wire connection for a much longer time".   Does this mean one can't install a subpanel that just has two hots and a ground, if you're only planning to use it for loads that are 240v with no neutral (such as most hot-water heaters and much HVAC equipment) ?

Comment: You can, @RustyShackleford but it has an ugly tendency to lead to "this would be a convenient place to pull a 120V circuit from" and resultant improper neutral-ground bonds.

Answer (score 4):

You don't understand how the "legs" work.  A 120V load, yes, only pulls off one "leg" or pole as we prefer to call it. Pole like a telephone pole, not pull like push/pull.

However, a 240V load *pulls off both legs*, er, poles.

So your 30A dryer is presently putting a ~23 amp load on both poles, leaving maybe 7 amps to spare on each of the two poles.

Could it run some cell phone chargers at 0.1 amps? Sure.  Lights at 1-2 amps?  Sure.  An EV charger at 12 or 16 amps?   Not while the dryer is running.  It would help to know your load.

Answer (score 1):

**No!**

You said in a comment that this scheme is to power a shed.

Most dryers use about 6kW. With the dryer running you can't use any one thing over 600 Watts in the shed and not more than 1200W total.   If someone's using a power saw and someone else turns on the dryer, the whole shed goes dark.  This assumes also that you have a 12/3 cable going out to the shed.  If it's a /2 you only get 600W total.

And strictly speaking you're not supposed to *plan* to run circuits at 100% capacity continuously.

This isn't a good way to plan power to an outbuilding.  Seriously, you're better off relying on batteries charged in the house for your lights and tools out there.

Comment: Dryers are allocated 5kW in the Article 220 load calculations, but still, the point stands, there isn't much margin here